# Can't install gnome extensions in Firefox - No ON/OFF button

Tags: firefox, gnome-shell-extension

I have a freshly installed Ubuntu 16.04 and I don't have the ON/OFF button in the gnome extensions site. I have no horizontal ribbons. Everything is installed as far as i know. Do you have any ideas about this?

Answer (score 0):

When installing Ubuntu GNOME, it installs a Firefox extension specifically designed to place the installation button on the GNOME marketplace via Firefox, you should install it before, reload the page, and suddenly it will appear.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and run

```
sudo apt-get install chrome-gnome-shell
```

Then download [this extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/gnome-shell-integration/)

You can now install extensions from [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/#)